$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the collection of all one-point sets.
I have seen that the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ which is generated by the collection of all one-point sets is the collection of all sets with a countable number of elements and their complements, and have more or less seen a proof of why. But I would like to know how one would come up with this set and then decide to prove it's the one we are looking for. How does someone reason to decide and test if that set is the expected $\sigma$-algebra?.

A $\sigma$-algebra is stable by countable union and complement. As it contains all singletons, it contains any countable union of them, that is it contains any countable set. And therefore it contains any complement of countable sets. Then by playing with the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra it becomes hard to find something that is neither countable nor the complement of a countable set. So you ask yourself whether you found it. And by definition of a generated $\sigma$-algebra, it suffices to show that your candidate (the set of countable sets and their complements) is a $\sigma$-algebra, which happens to be true.
